# Merge Sort in C using Recursion

Tags: c, sorting, recursion, mergesort

This is my code for merge sort in C. I'm not able to understand what the issue is here. My knowledge of pointers is not that much. The merge function takes in 2 arrays and merges them. the sort function is a recursive function which is supposed to sort the array.

```
int * merge(int *fir, int n, int *sec, int m){
    int res[m+n];
    int x=0, y=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m+n; i++){
        if(*(fir+x)<=*(sec+y)){
            res[i] = *(fir+x);
            x++;
        }else{
            res[i] = *(sec+y);
            y++;
        }

    }
    return res;
}

int * sort(int A[], int n){
    if(n == 1){
        return A;
    }
    int mid = n/2;
    int AL[mid], AR[n-mid];
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++){
        AL[i] = A[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-mid; i++){
        AR[i] = A[i+mid];
    }
    int *BL, *BR;
    BL = sort(AL, mid);
    BR = sort(AR, n-mid);
    return(merge(BL, mid, BR, n-mid));
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int A[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    int *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = sort(A, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(sortedArray+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output

````
q8.c:16:9: warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'res' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
        return res;
               ^~~
1 warning generated.
7
23 12 56 67 11 99 97
97 32766 539779418 32767 -2002825496 32767 6 %```
````

Comment: You are reading beyond the bounds of the array. When you merge the arrays, there are four cases. Your code misses the two cases where one array is exhausted and you take the first item from the other one.

Comment: There's also the problem that you return the address of a local array. `res`. That array will no longer be valid after you return from `merge` and the pointer to it will be "stale". (that's what the warning is about.)

Comment: For `*(fir+x)` you can just write `fir[x]`  which is easier to read.

Comment: Yeah, I understood both my mistakes. Thank you so much for pointing them out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here: First, you merge your partial arrays into a temporary local array, which yoes out of bounds after you return from `merge`. The pointer you return points to invlid memory. That's what the warning about.

Second, you don't check whether you are reading beyond the limits of the partial arrays when you merge: The condition `x < n` must be true when you access `fir`, likewise for `y < m` and `sec`.

You are also causing confusion by returning a pointer to the first element of the sorted or merged arrays. That suggests that you create new sorted and merged arrays (and that's what you try to do in `merge`). This is okay for garbage-collected morern languages, but C doesn't work that way.

In C, if you need new memory, you must allocate it and later free it explicitly. In a recursive function like yours, this is tedious, because you are interested only in the final sorted array, not in the intermediate results. Therefore, C sorting algorithms usually work "in place": The same memory is used thoughout the sorting and elements are swapped. The original order of the elements is lost unless you make a copy before sorting.

For merge sort, you need auxiliary memory. In your case, you use the temporary arrays `AL` and `AR`, which are copies of the contents of the original array, `A`. Now when you merge, you can merge `AL` and `AR` back into `A`.

So istead of creating a ephemeral local array, pass in `A` so that it can be filled with the sorted elements:

```
void sort(int A[], int n)
{
    if (n > 1) {
        int mid = n / 2;
        int AL[mid], AR[n - mid];

        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) AL[i] = A[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < n - mid; i++) AR[i] = A[i + mid];
        
        sort(AL, mid);
        sort(AR, n - mid);
        
        merge(A, AL, mid, AR, n - mid);
    }
}
```

Your `merge` function is now very similar to the one you has before, only that you have the result array as parameter and that you must catch the out-of-bound cases before accessing elements with `[]`.

```
void merge(int *res, const int *fir, int n, const int *sec, int m)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < m + n; i++) {
        if      (x == n)            res[i] = sec[y++];
        else if (y == m)            res[i] = fir[x++];
        else if (fir[x] <= sec[y])  res[i] = fir[x++];
        else                        res[i] = sec[y++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I understood what I have done wrong. Thank you so much for helping me out!